# Cannot debug sharepoint solution

Tags: debugging

I have really strange problems with debuging sharepoint solution.
Sometimes i cannot debug sharepoint webparts. Now i have such situation and nothing helps. I tried to restart computer\recycle pools\iisreset
[image]
Problem that when i am attaching to processes visual studio starts to really slowly loads some symbols. 
[image]

and after 10 minutes i have message:

[image]

What can cause such problems? I also tried to set huge timeouts and its not helps either.

Studio running under admin rights.

Also ping was changed and tested in both 'enabled' and 'disabled':

[image]

And without results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually caused by IIS Health Monitoring thinking that the web service that you are debugging has locked up and it needs to be restarted.   Check out [this post](http://www.shubho.net/2011/02/debugging-timeout-visual-studio-iis7.html) for more details.

Comment: I tried this. But in post author had timeouts and i cannot even attach to processes.

Comment: How much RAM is on your dev machine and are you running your SQL server on that machine as well?

Comment: Yes, on the same machine. I have 8GB or RAM

Comment: I assume a multi-core processor as well.  You might want to restart SQL once before diving into any serious debugging sessions as it has a tendency to eat RAM.

Comment: Also, it is helpful if you warm up the site prior to debugging it by loading a page that contains your custom code in the browser prior to attaching the debugger